# Definir dimensão em px com base em dimensão em %

Tags: javascript

Estou com problemas ao desenvolver um script de resize

```
function resizeImagePreview(){
    var imageHolder = document.getElementById("image-holder");
    imageHolder.style.width = "25%";
    console.log(imageHolder.style.width);
    imageHolder.style.height = imageHolder.style.width + "px";
    console.log(imageHolder.style.height);
}resizeImagePreview();
```

O script não apresenta nenhum erro, porém, o height do elemento não é definido, o que está causando o erro e, como corrigir ?

Comment: Primeiro você atribui "25%" ao `width`, depois define que `heigth` será `width + "px"`, que resulta em `25%px`. Não parece fazer sentido. Quais são os valores exibidos no console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu código:

```
function resizeImagePreview(){
    var imageHolder = document.getElementById("image-holder");
    imageHolder.style.width = "25%";
    console.log(imageHolder.style.width);
    imageHolder.style.height = imageHolder.style.width + "px";
    console.log(imageHolder.style.height);
}resizeImagePreview();
```

Na terceira linha, você atribui o valor `25%` ao atributo `width`. Na quinta linha, você atribui ao atributo `height` o valor de `width` concatenado com a *string* `px`. Considerando que o atributo terá o valor `25%`, dada a linha 3, o valor de `height` será `25%px`, que não faz sentido algum e o navegador provavelmente descarta.

Agora, se a sua intenção é obter o valor em pixels que o `width` possui após ser atribuído `25%`, então você deve usar a propriedade `offsetWidth` do elemento. Ficaria algo como:

```
function resizeImagePreview(){
    var imageHolder = document.getElementById("image-holder");
    imageHolder.style.width = "25%";
    console.log(imageHolder.style.width);
    imageHolder.style.height = imageHolder.offsetWidth + "px";
    console.log(imageHolder.style.height);
}resizeImagePreview();
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
function resizeImagePreview(){
    var imageHolder = document.getElementById("image-holder");
    imageHolder.style.width = "25%";
    console.log(imageHolder.style.width);
    imageHolder.style.height = imageHolder.offsetWidth + "px";
    console.log(imageHolder.style.height);
}resizeImagePreview();
```

```css
#image-holder {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-holder"></div>
```

Comment: Boa, eu tinha esquecido do `offsetWidth`. Provavelmente sua resposta tem performance melhor que a minha.

Comment: perfeito, eu também havia esquecido de offsetWidth

Comment: Uma coisa de que me dei conta só agora: o `offsetWidth` vai incluir padding e bordas na conta, então atenção. Tem também o `clientWidth`, que só inclui o padding e não inclui bordas. Se essa div estiver com `box-sizing: content-box` (o padrão), nenhuma dessas propriedades bate com a largura, se houver bordas e/ou padding.

Comment: @bfavaretto Mas `padding` e `border` não são modificadores das dimensões? Digo, faz sentido ser considerado no `width` visto que o elemento tem sua largura aumentada com o `padding` e `border`, diferente do `margin` que não modifica as dimensões.

Comment: Sim, depende do que ele quer. É que as "peculiaridades" do box model + as peculiaridades dessas propriedades podem confundir.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem o que você quer, é necessário ler a largura [calculada pelo browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) e definir a altura com base nela. Algo assim:

```
var estilos = getComputedStyle(imageHolder);

// estilos.width já é uma string com 'px' no final.
// se quiser como número, usar parseInt(estilos.width, 10)
imageHolder.style.height = estilos.width;
```